# Allow to hide a hot network question

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, sidebar

NOTE: This questions is a duplicate of [Hide Hot Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/hide-hot-questions), not of the question currently marked as a duplicated...

Sometimes I click on the hot network questions finding them very interesting. I have few sites that I love *reading*, but sometimes the questions don't appeal me at all. So every time I see the logo, I have to remember a) if I have already clicked it* and b) if I have already decided not to read it. This adds *some* effort to the task, discouraging me from repeating it. So I propose:

- Being able to **hide questions manually**. If I'm really not interested in a question, show a small `x` when I hover that question to allow me to stop this from appearing again.
- **Don't show the questions** already visited. If I have already visited it, please don't show it again.

I think with these two features the **hot network question** relevance would be improved greatly.

PS, this could also yield some basic capabilities for a simple AI on what we like or what we don't and show more relevant questions, but that's another topic (;

* Some sites make the visited links lighter, some sites make them darker. Duh.

Comment: Same issue here, this would be really helpful.

Comment: related, on meta.se: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/hide-hot-questions

Comment: No @sphanley, I don't want to hide the whole section, only few individual questions (and new ones appearing). So it *is* a dup of meta.se, but not a dup of the meta.so that you marked (I already read that one) (:

Comment: That's fair - I marked it as a duplicate because in the comments for that meta.so post, the OP indicates they feel their post was a duplicate of that same meta.se post, which this definitely also duplicates.

Comment: part of the issue is probably that some hot questions [stick for too long](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/165773) and as a result are repeatedly displayed in sidebar for too long. Granted, it became better after [shuffling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/165773) was introduced, but not much. Some questions, especially from smaller sites, still stick over there for 4-5-6 days

Comment: I'm not a big fan of hiding as soon as it's read. I find I sometimes don't have time to read a really in-depth question/answer, so I come back to it later. Being able to hide it manually would be super helpful though.

Comment: I made a simple userscript for this, while there is no response. Greasemonkey or equivalent required. https://gist.github.com/kroltan/3786844135f996bdff36

Comment: I also agree it's not a duplicate of the indicated question. That question is about the whole pane, while this one asks for treatment of individual questions.

Answer (score 4):

UserScript?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide HNQ
// @namespace   so_ext
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?stackoverflow\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?serverfault\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?superuser\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?stackexchange\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?askubuntu\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?mathoverflow\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/discuss\.area51\.stackexchange\.com/.*$/
// @include /^https?:\/\/stackapps\.com/.*$/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

if (Math.random() < 0.25)
  {
   document.getElementById("hot-network-questions").innerHTML = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Bg-easter-eggs.jpg/800px-Bg-easter-eggs.jpg' width='220px'/>"; 
  }
else
  {
   document.getElementById("hot-network-questions").style = "display: none";    
  }
```

Its a shame that the Greasemonkey header is <strike>14 times</strike> twice the size of the actual code.

Comment: *Its a shame that the Greasemonkey header is 14 times the size of the actual code* ... add an easter-egg?

Comment: @rene - Like replacing the Hot Questions with [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Easter_eggs#/media/File:Bg-easter-eggs.jpg)? Or is that too obvious? :)

Comment: I would definitely install if that was added ;)

Comment: @rene - Ask and ye shall receive.

Comment: [much better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HpHmV.png) thanks!