# Filter out tags from "Hot Network Questions" sidebar

Tags: support, hot-questions

After searching on Meta I found out that it's possible to only ALLOW questions with specific tags.

What I would like to do is the opposite. Lately it's been inundated by GOT questions (sorry, not interested) and I would like to exclude them.

I tried to ignore the tag in the specific community but it didn't seem to work

Not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281862/allow-to-hide-a-hot-network-question): I'm asking to apply the "ignore tag" filter to the Hot Questions, not for the ability to hide specific questions.

Comment: Ironically, I would like this too for just the reason that I don't want to see spoilers until I've actually caught up

Comment: Note that with few exceptions (due to refreshing speed) we edit out spoilery titles on M&TV for this very reason.

Comment: If this is a request for a multi-site functionality (e.g. hide questions from other sites based on tags on those sites in HNQ network-wide), this feature request (not a support question) should probably be posted on MSE, not MSO.

Comment: Feature requests can be posted on any Meta site the asker chooses, @Tyler. The team follows all of them, and has made this clear on multiple occasions. It is perfectly valid for users who primarily use Stack Overflow to make feature requests on its Meta site.

Comment: Not an answer, but I hid the HNQ and haven't looked back, you might consider trying it temporarily.

Comment: 99% of the SO hot questions are in tags I'm ignoring too. Always annoying to see an interesting-looking title only to find it's yet another C++ question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about Stack Overflow specifically, and should probably be on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TRiG I actually thought I was posting there. Can we move the post?

Comment: It can be done, yes. (Flag for a mod.) Might be simpler to ask again there, as mods are busy. For what it's worth, I don't agree that it's a duplicate: hiding an entire tag is a subtly different use case.